# Dynamic MultiValueField in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I am trying to create a custom widget based on a MultiValueField that dynamically creates its fields. Something along the lines of:

```
class MyField(MultiValueField):
    def __init__(self, my_param, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = []
        for field in my_param.all():
            fields.append(forms.ChoiceField(
              widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'some_class'})))

    super(MyField, self).__init__(
        self, fields=tuple(fields), *args, **kwargs)
```

And a form using the field like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    multi_field = MyField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['multi_field'].my_param = self.initial['car_types'].another
```

I am somehow stuck at the moment. How can I pass a parameter (e.g. my_param) to MyField's **init**() method when the param is only know from within MyForm's constructor (e.g. self.initial['car_types'].another)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate your field inside `__init__`:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['multi_field'] = MyField(self.initial['car_types'].another)
```

Comment: ... but what if `FieldError: Unknown field(s) ` appear because our Model and MyForm don't know this 'multi_field' - a custom field given in fieldsets of our ModelAdmin and required to be defined in MyForm class.